# Why 'fixed' element can't have both 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' properties

Tags: jquery, css

There is element on the page:

```
#current_colors_container{
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 23%;
    left: 1.6%; }
```

If I leave `margin-top` it doesn't cover up element above while scrolling up, if I leave `margin-bottom` it doesn't cover up absolute element of page in the bottom while scrolling down.

But both properties doesn't work, works only one of them (first in the list), and I can't get why - I expected it to have both margins while scrolling in both directions.

And my attempt to fix it with JQ doesn't work:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($("#current_colors_container").length>0){

            var bottom_nav=$('#bottom_nav').offset().top;
            var container_top=$("#current_colors_container").offset().top
            var color_container=container_top+$("#current_colors_container").height();


         if( bottom_nav<=color_container){
         $("#current_colors_container").css({"margin-top":"", "margin-bottom":"70px"})
         }
   }

});
```

Is there any pure CSS solution? Or how should I fix my JS function?

**UPD**

Now, JQ fix works, If I remove `margin` from ID CSS and provide it through classes (with functions `addClass` and `removeClass`) but, this solution makes #container 'jump' (shift quickly) before be fixed above or below other elements, and I don't like this, I would like it just stop floating.

Comment: have you tried, top: yourValue; ?

Comment: @soderslatt, I will try, but I suppose that doesn't suits me because #containet height is dynamic

Comment: If you could mock up this problem in a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that would be very helpful. Right now I am at a loss for what you are describing as having a position of fixed does not change how margins work, other than the fact that the element is out of flow so it doesn't interact with anything other than positional attributes (top,left,etc)